# May expose internal representation by storing an externally mutable object

Tags: java, gradle, model-view-controller, spotbugs

I have an mvc structure for my projecy but spotbugs give me this error
(M V EI2: new it.unibo.unibomber.game.view.ExplosionView(Explosion) may expose internal representation by storing an externally mutable object into ExplosionView.controller  At ExplosionView.java:[line 31])
Controller:

```
public final class Explosion implements GameLoop {
    private final ExplosionView view;
    private final ExplosionImpl model;
    private List<Entity> explode;

    public List<Entity> getExplode() {
        return new ArrayList<>(explode);
    }

    public Explosion() {
        view = new ExplosionView(this);
        model = new ExplosionImpl();
        explode = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

View:

```
public final class ExplosionView implements GameLoop {
    private final Explosion controller;

    public ExplosionView(final Explosion controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }
```

How can i do??

Comment: `ExplosionView` has a reference to `Explosion`, and `Explosion` is not immutable, it exposes `List<Entity> explode` through the getter. If you want to make it immutable, one option would be to keep the relationship between  ExplosionView  and Explosion  unidirectional

Comment: @EmanuelTrandafir how can i make unidirectional comunication? I need data from controller for draw in view.